# Increment operation in C: double increment in in one expression (C89)

Tags: c, c89

Why the result for the variable c in the following code is -5?

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 3, c=0;
    c = b++ - b++ * a; 
    printf("\n%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, another question, why `d = b++ - b++` is -1 after this one?

Comment: Because it is UB

Comment: got it. thanks @0___________